# How to create a proxy socket for different types such as HTTP / Socks / Normal in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, proxy

I have been trying to create a proxy socket in using .Net and then specify the proxy settings. But it has not been able to set the required proxy settings. Code example showing required setting and appreciate if you could support.

```
Socket proxySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            /*
             * These values has to be set with a proxy
             * 
            ProxySettings proxySettings = new ProxySettings();
            proxySettings.ProxyIPEndpoint = proxyEndPoint;
            proxySettings.ProxyType = proxyType;

            //proxySocket.ProxyUser = proxyUsername;
            //proxySocket.ProxyPass = proxyPassword;
            */
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do and what you expect the socket to do. What should this do and why has it "not been able"?

Comment: You seem to want some kind of wrapper class that will manage the proxy protocol on top of the socket. This isn't built into .Net, The only proxy that is built in is HTTP and not at the socket level. Third party solutions are available, or you can write your own class which accepts proxy settings and wraps around a socket

Comment: @JamesBarrass, Yes exactly that is what i needed. Yes i checked even with the latest .Net framework (even 4.5) and it has only HTTP socket and the other one WebProxy is now been deprecated. Looks like either has to write up own wrapper or use a 3rd part solution. Thanks